# Getting error when I try to send an ajax call to a script on same server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I'm getting the error

> “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource”

When I try to do this in jQuery

```
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:52930/api/person"
    })
        .done(function( msg ) {
            alert(  msg );
        });
```

To a ASP script that is running on port `52930`. The url returns a JSON array. Why does it give this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: Search for *Asp.Net CORS*

Comment: I enabled CORS in all controllers now but it still gives the same error. Do I need to change anything on the jquery side?

Comment: [Perhaps using `jsonp`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5473299/1267304).

Comment: I'll try that in a bit but is this right when I enable it for all controllers in WebApiConfig?
`var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:52930", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);`

Comment: I also tried using the websites origin which was just `http://127.0.0.1` but still same thing

Comment: Using jsonp gives me this error instead: `jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:52930/api/person?callback=jQuery2140005036372845720116_1494955262090&_=1494955262091 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: It's working now! The problem after enabling CORS was that I didn't have data in the database. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304817/basic-ajax-request-gets-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-t/